# Custom AMI launch failed with error In order to use this AWS Marketplace product you need to accept terms and subscribe

Tags: amazon-web-services, marketplace

I am relatively new to AWS.
I have subscribed to CIS image from market place from my account and created a custom AMI with CIS image as base . I am able to create new instances from my custom AMI.
However when I shared my custom AMI to a different account , its throwing below error.
In order to use this AWS Marketplace product you need to accept terms and subscribe. To do so please visit https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=d5t1p864uxakfqniibnyr0voy.

If my understanding is correct ,I am sharing the custom AMI to other accounts and they dont need subscription for base CIS AMI .Is this the case or Is subscription required for all shared accounts for base CIS AMI ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing a marketplace product with other accounts, like a Marketplace AMI in your case, then other accounts still need to accept the terms of that product. This can be done by going to marketplace subscriptions and subscribing to that product from all accounts. This just subscribes you to the AMI but doesn't  charge you anything until you start running an instance based on that AMI.